# Regex capture multiple matches in every line that starts with expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to capture each word following a `(` or `,` and followed by `$`, on lines starting with `function`, but I'm having trouble capturing every word.

For example, in this line `function f(string $string, int $int1, int $int2, $var, array $array = null)` I want to capture `string`, `int`, `int`, `array`.

My tries include:
`[\(,](.+?)\$`,
`function[^\(]*\(([^\$]*)\$[^,]+,([^\$]*)\$`
and everything in between

I'm testing here:
https://regex101.com/r/rosWhD/3

Ps: the objective is to write a script to remove php function type hinting, and make my app compatible with php5

Comment: will there be a space before $ sign?

Comment: Use a parser instead, regex isn't a suitable tool for such use cases

Comment: You can do something like [`JS demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/uaghk1xr/) but best option is to use language parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex isn't the right tool for the job (that would be a language parser), but if you're determined to use it, the following should satisfy your needs:

`(?<=(?:function\s*\w*\()|(?:,\s*))[\w]+(?=\s*\$)`

- `(?<=(?:function\s*\w*\()|(?:,\s*))` Assert without matching that the preceding string contains `function [optional name](` or `,` followed by optional spaces
- `[\w]+` Match some word characters (but at least one) from `a-zA-Z_`
- `(?=\s*\$)` Assert without matching that the following string contains optional spaces and a literal `$` character

It finds a collection of word characters (no numbers) that is preceded by either `function [optional name](` or `,` and is followed by `$`. Will not accept "types" with digits/spaces in them, nor will it match "types" that are not followed by a variable.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/rosWhD/6)